# What am I able to do if the school wont help me? Can I deal with it in court?

Tags: advisor, united-states, undergraduate, law

Im a third year in college and my advisor hasn't talked to me since the beginning of my second year. 3 semesters counting now, I am trying to apply for classes and I cant because I have a registration hold. The hold say I need to talk to an advisor. Still no contact, I called the departments but ive been tossed around dept to dept. If I bring it to the dean and I still dont get my classes. What are my options? I loose financial aid and a semester of class. If worse comes to worse can I tackle this legally with a lawyer?

Comment: Do you have an advisor that has officially accepted you as a student or been assigned to you as an advisor? Your question is a bit unclear in that regard.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to make a physical visit to the advisor's office?

Comment: Are you advised by a staff person or a faculty member? At my university most undergrad class selection advising is done by staff. In that case, I would contact the advisor’s supervisor (probably your department chair).